# Arabic Text issue with PDFKit plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, arabic, pdfkit

To generate dynamic PDF files, I'm using [PDFKit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkit).
The generation works fine, but I'm having trouble displaying arabic characters, even after installing an arabic font.
Also, **Arabic text is generated correctly, but I believe the word order is incorrect.**

As an example,

I'm currently using pdfkit: "0.11.0"

Text: مرحبا كيف حالك ( Hello how are you )

Font: [Amiri-Regular.ttf](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Amiri?subset=arabic&query=amiri)

```
const PDFDocument = require("pdfkit");
var doc = new PDFDocument({
  size: [595.28, 841.89],
  margins: {
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
});
const customFont = fs.readFileSync(`${_tmp}/pdf/Amiri-Regular.ttf`);
doc.registerFont(`Amiri-Regular`, customFont);
doc.fontSize(15);
doc.font(`Amiri-Regular`).fillColor("black").text("مرحبا كيف حالك");
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${_tmp}/pdf/arabic.pdf`));
doc.end();
```

OUTPUT:

[PDF with arabic text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqmua.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this problem allowed me to go through here, but unfortunately I am not convinced by the answers posted and even add a library to change the direction of the text with pdfkit.
after several minutes on the pdfkit guide docs, here is the solution:

```
doc.text("مرحبا كيف حالك", {features: ['rtla']})
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right the order of the Arabic words are wrong and you habe to set-up the direction of the sentence

try to use this

```js
doc.rtl(true);
```

or This as a configuration for single line or text

```js
doc.font(`Amiri-Regular`).fillColor("black").text("مرحبا كيف حالك", {rtl: true});
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? I was looking it up and saw this: https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit/issues/640. Or am I using the wrong git repo?

Comment: YES. once before i tried the 2nd statement and it works. i mean to define the direction as a 2nd parameter in `text()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Answer adapted from the info [here](https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit/issues/219):

1. install the package: `npm install twitter_cldr`
2. Run this function to generate the text:

```
const TwitterCldr = TwitterCldrLoader.load("en");
     
private maybeRtlize(text: string) {
  if (this.isHebrew(text)) {
    var bidiText = TwitterCldr.Bidi.from_string(text, { direction: "RTL" });
    bidiText.reorder_visually();
    return bidiText.toString();
  } else {
    return text;
  }
}
     
Value = maybeRtlize("مرحبا كيف حالك")

doc.font(`Amiri-Regular`).fillColor("black").text(Value);
```

Another method that's also possible is to reverse the text (using something such as `text.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');`, however while this will work for simple arabic text, it will start having issues the moment you introduce English-numericals for example. so the first method is recommended.

Comment: The problem with `text.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');` that the text will still `ltr` and Arabic is `rtl` language.

Comment: Yup. It will work for plain text without any numbers/periods/etc. But the usage of reverse is definitely not a recommended solution. Mentioned it nevertheless since someone might make use of it somehow.

Comment: Yes, I tried, but the outcome was incorrect.

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1LSq.png)

Comment: text.split(' ').reverse().join(' ') | Yes, it works fine for a few words, but it does not work for a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do one of the following depending on your needs

1 ) if you have a low number of `doc.text` functions used to generate the document you can add `{features: ['rtla']}` as second parameter to the function as follows:

```
doc.text('تحية طيبة وبعد', { features: ['rtla'] });
```

2 ) if you have many calls to `doc.text` instead of adding `{features: ['rtla']}` as a parameter to each call, you can reverse all you text before hand by iterating on your data object and reversing the word order as follows:

```
let str = "السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته";

str = str.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');

doc.text(str);
```